# Possible to get around an Activity requiring to extend both MapActivity and another Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps

I have an Activity which extends MapActivity (to show a MapView) and contains a Fragment. It works fine when targetting Api 11 (Sdk 3.0) and above.

However, I'd like to release my app for phones running earlier versions of Android (2.2 at least). To do so I need to use the Android support package and my Activity should extend FragmentActivity but this is not possible as my Activity also needs to extend MapActivity in order to show a MapView containing Google map data.

Anyone come across this or a similar problem and can suggest any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done it but this may help you:

[Description of MapActivity and FragmentActivity](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15347)

Comment: Thanks for the link Kaediil. Not the neatest solutions suggested there but gives me options!